# Global find and replace in Trello

Tags: trello, search

In Trello, is there a way to search and replace text across all cards in a given list?

Comment: Where does the text you want to replace reside on the card? The card description or on a checklist, or comment?

Answer (score 2):

Trello doesn't provide "search and replace" functionality.  Best you can do is use the API to find the relevant cards:

```
https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/search#get-1-search
```

...then loop through the results, calling e.g. https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/card#put-1-cards-card-id-or-shortlink-desc to update the description.  You'd need to do the same for whichever fields you wanted to update.